# Angular dropdown switching from hard coded data to live data from service

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have a Angular 5 dropdown that works fine with hard coded data, but I need to switch it to live data.  The problem is that the live data is plain array.

This is what currently works

**HTML**

```
<select...
  <option *ngFor="let activityType of activityTypes" [ngValue]="activityType.Id">
        {{activityType.Activity}}
  </option>
```

**Typescript Component**

```
activityTypes: any[];

this.activityTypes = [
        { Id: 1, Activity: "Select One" },
        { Id: 2, Activity: "Insert" },
        { Id: 2, Activity: "Update" },
        { Id: 3, Activity: "Delete" },          
];
```

However, here is my issue, I'm pulling down data from a service and the data looks like this array

```
this.activityTypes v["INSERT", "UPDATE"]
                      0: "INSERT"
                      1: "UPDATE"
```

[click to see dev tool image output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xS2si.png)

**Now, how do I use the array to bind to the dropdown?**
Clearly I would want to have values set as "0", "1" of the array .. then the DISPLAY ( which is my Activity in the hard coded example)  I would want it to hold "INSERT" and "UPDATE"  ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array index as value of option and data as label

```
<select...
  <option *ngFor="let activityType of activityTypes; let i = index" [ngValue]="i">
        {{activityType}}
  </option>
```

**Solution2:** You can create array of objects as:

```
this.activityTypes = this.activityTypes.map((currElement, index) => {
  let obj = {
    Id: index,
    Activity: currElement
  };
  return obj;
});
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain this a bit?  What if I created a class with data types in typescript and wanted to set Id = 0,1 etc..  and Activity = "Insert", Update" etc..   ?

Comment: greatly appreciate it !